# Setting focus to the User Name TextBox field of an ASP.Net LoginView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, findcontrol, loginview

Using this ASP.Net LoginView, we would like to set focus on the User Name TextBox when it's loaded on the web page:

```
<asp:LoginView 
    ID="loginViewMain" 
    runat="server">

    <LoggedInTemplate>
        <asp:LoginName 
            ID="loginName" 
            runat="server"
            FormatString="Hello, {0}!<br/><br/> You have successfully<br/> logged onto the staff site." />

        <br/>
        <br/>

        (<asp:LoginStatus ID="loginStatus" runat="server" />)

        <br/>
        <br/>

    </LoggedInTemplate>

    <AnonymousTemplate>
        <asp:LoginStatus 
            ID="loginStatus" 
            runat="server" />
    </AnonymousTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

This is the code-behind we tried to use to get focus on the User Name TextBox:

```
Private Sub loginViewMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles loginViewMain.Load

    Dim objContentPlaceHolder As ContentPlaceHolder
    Dim objLoginView As LoginView
    Dim objUserName As TextBox

    objContentPlaceHolder = CType(Me.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolderBody"), ContentPlaceHolder)

    If Not objContentPlaceHolder Is Nothing Then

        objLoginView = CType(objContentPlaceHolder.FindControl("loginViewMain"), LoginView)

        If Not objLoginView Is Nothing Then
            objUserName = objLoginView.FindControl("UserName")
            objUserName.Focus()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Execution does get into this If structure:

```
If Not objLoginView Is Nothing Then
```

Can you tell me what else I need to add in the If structure of this coding to get hold of the User Name TextBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that without the need to know the details of the LoginView control. Instead use JavaScript to find the first textbox and focus on it.

Add the following code in your code behind file:

```
var script = string.Format(@"
    var inputs = document.getElementById('{0}').getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {{
        var inp = inputs[i];
        if (inp.type.toUpperCase() !== 'TEXT') continue;
        inp.focus();
        inp.select();
        break;
    }}", this.LoginView.ClientID);

// register the script
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "login focus", script, true);
```

or in VB.NET:

```
Dim script = String.Format(
    "var inputs = document.getElementById('{0}').getElementsByTagName('input');" &
    "for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {{" &
    "    var inp = inputs[i];" & 
    "    if (inp.type.toUpperCase() !== 'TEXT') continue;" & 
    "    inp.focus();" & 
    "    inp.select();" &
    "    break;" & 
    "}}", Me.LoginView.ClientID)

' register the script
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, TypeOf(this), "login focus", script, True)
```

Comment: Looks nice. Can you include a vb.net version of this coding that I can place in the code-behind?

Comment: Thanks for the coding but we looked on Google and could not find how to place this in the markup of the web page. Is this coding supposed to go into the code-behind?

Comment: I found the correct formatting for your script. I'm including it as part of the posting. I do get an error messages that states: "Input string was not in the correct format"

Comment: @Emad-ud-deen I've rejected your edit of this answer containing outcome of your test - use comments for that.

Comment: Ok. It's the first time tying that. :-)

Answer (score 2):

FindControl only searches one tree level deep.

Try using a [recursive function](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/06/recursive-pagefindcontrol.html) instead

for example:

```
private Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id) 
{ 
    if (root.ID == id)
    { 
        return root; 
    } 

    foreach (Control c in root.Controls) 
    { 
        Control t = FindControlRecursive(c, id); 
        if (t != null) 
        { 
            return t; 
        } 
    } 

    return null; 
}
```

Then the call will be

```
objLoginView = CType(FindControlRecursive(objContentPlaceHolder, "loginViewMain"), LoginView);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you show the needed coding we need to do it?

Comment: check the link and post if you get stuck

Comment: Thanks. I will convert it to VB.Net and try it.

Comment: Since I don't know the actual name of the User Name TextBox that the LoginView gives the control I can't use your coding for that. However, your coding works very nicely in finding a control so I'm going to use it in other parts of the application. I will try to use the coding from Knaģis.